# How to get a gridview to show all table rows when no text is entered in a dependent textbox?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, gridview, sqldatasource

The below works correctly and filters my gridview based on the text entered in my textbox.

When no text is entered into my textbox I get no results and cannot understand why.

**MY QUESTION**

How to get a gridview to show **all** table rows when no text is entered in the textbox?

**MSSQL**

```
@Search nvarchar(50)

SELECT  [table].[column]
FROM    [table]
WHERE   [table].[column] LIKE '%' + @Search + '%' OR COALESCE(@Search,'') = ''
```

**MARKUP**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" RunAt="Server" Text=""/>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlSearch" RunAt="Server" SelectCommand="spSearch" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Type="String" Name="Search" ControlID="txtSearch" PropertyName="Text"/>
  </SelectParameters> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**RESULTS TO GRIDVIEW**

I have tried and tested many methods found on here however all return 0 results when string is empty.

Comment: I tried your query with <<< declare @Search nvarchar(50); set @search='' >>>. It seems working correct, returning all the rows.

Comment: The SQL code looks correct, are you sure it's being called if txtSearch is empty? Is there some validation on the page that could be preventing the call?

Comment: It might be worth trying setting the SqlDataSource's **CancelSelectOnNullParameter** to **false**

Comment: I also think the code is correct so am missing something obvious. It works fine unless txtSearch is empty cant check what is being passed out because the code is in datasource and not in vb.

Comment: @ Netricity. Holy S**t, that works.
If you post it as an answer I will mark it as such.
I have not used CancelSelectOnNullParameter before and would appreciate it if you can briefly outline its function in your answer.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [CancelSelectOnNullParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.cancelselectonnullparameter.aspx) - by default, this **prevents** the select command from being called when a select parameter's value is null. After setting it to `false`, the select SP will then still get called even if the text box is empty, e.g.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlSearch" RunAt="Server" 
    CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false" ...>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The SqlDataSource seems a bit misleading to me here, because TextBox.Text returns String.Empty when it's empty, not null, therefore I wouldn't expect to have to mess with CancelSelectOnNullParameter for a TextBox, but it seems we have to.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of coalesce you may have a if block which checks if the @search parameter is empty or not as shown below..

```
if @search is not empty 
  SELECT  [table].[column]
  FROM    [table]
  WHERE   [table].[column] LIKE '%' + @Search + '%' OR COALESCE(@Search,'') = ''
else
  SELECT  [table].[column]
  FROM    [table]
  WHERE   [table].[column]
```