# SQL query won't show all records if bot critera is null or ''

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I created an ASP.NET webpage with C# and SQL Server 2014.

I have a `GridView1` with a `SqlDataSource` that has a `SELECT` query with 2 criteria in controls on the web page.

Both are DropDownLists with `Decimal(18,0)` values.

I would like set a `WHERE` clause so that gridview will return:

- All records if both criteria is null or
- If one of criteria is fulfilled, show records using only this criteria, other criteria is null or
- If both criteria are fulfilled, show records using both criteria

Some kind of a cascading filtering.

I tried this (on page load):

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

`DropDownList1` and `DropDownList2` both are set:

```
 AppendDataBoundItems="True" and <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
```

So DDL controls does not contain any value or text on page load.

In this case I expected that `GridView1` shows me all the records - but it shows nothing.

SQL query statement is:

```
SELECT....
WHERE 
    ([rentnr] = @rentnr) AND ([apartman] = @apartman) 
    OR ([apartman]= @apartman) AND (@rentnr IS NULL) 
    OR ([rentnr] = @rentrn) AND (@apartman IS NULL) 
    OR (@rentnr IS NULL) AND (@apartman IS NULL)
```

- `@rent` is data from DDL1
- `@apartman` is data from DDL2

What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Interesting. I see `([apartman]= @apartman) AND (@rentnr IS NULL) ` again. Just a reminder, you may run into bad query plan if using query like this. Using dynamic query could avoid this issue. See kimberly's blog about this: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/high-performance-procedures/

Comment: Hi Marc, thank you for you advice. English is not my native language so my grammar is poor and as I was in hurry and my text is as is. Programming is my hobby and I'm beginner and self-taught using Google search and translate. So pleas understand my position. I'm open to learn and and grateful for the help. Thanks for link I'll read it. Furthermore, I create a new gridview and set only one condition - dropdownlist value wihich is null or just empty string. And again I can't get display all records if dropdownlist has no value.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT....
WHERE 
    ( ([rentnr] = @rentnr) AND ([apartman] = @apartman) )
    OR ( ([apartman]= @apartman) AND (@rentnr IS NULL) )
    OR ( ([rentnr] = @rentrn) AND (@apartman IS NULL) )
    OR ( (@rentnr IS NULL) AND (@apartman IS NULL) )
```

Note, I've added extra ( ) for condition groups.

@rentnr and @apartman when not filled in may be passed to SQL not as NULLs but as 0s, because you said the DDL lists them as Decimals. Then you need one more OR condition:

```
    OR ( (@rentnr = 0) AND (@apartman = 0) )
```

HTH

Comment: Hi Andrews, thank you for you code. After implement it everything works fine inside Visual Studio/Configure Data Source screen where you can test or edit query. Works just as I expected just like my previous was too. But when I run it from browser problem isn't solved. On page load DDLs are empty, and GV is not showing all records - shows nothing! If I select some value inside just one DDL nothing. If I select both DDLs values only in this case records are shown. As I sad in above comment to Marc, I tested a new one GV with only one condition in DDL - got same behavior.

Comment: @jastog thanks for the update. You just need to see what GV sends to SQL when DDLs are empty. This can easily be done with SQL Server Profiler. Do you have the SQL Server Management Studio + Profiler installed?

Comment: Hi Andrews, no I have not installed Profiler but I'll do it. I this moment I ma very happy that i found a solution: CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false" added to SqlDataSource in asp code. After several days of frustration! Kind regards!

Comment: @jastog I'm glad you got it solved. Note, if any of the current answers was helpful for you, you are welcome to vote them up (see the arrows around 0 at the left). If you had SQL profiler installed you would be able to catch the exact SQL request which grid sends to DB upon initial page load and see if it sent 0s or NULLs or empty strings ('') when DDL values were not set. Then you would be able to add a proper OR condition to the actual SQL.

Answer (score 1):

finally I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564536/how-to-get-a-gridview-to-show-all-table-rows-when-no-text-is-entered-in-a-depend).
The key is **CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"**  ! I added it to asp:SqlDataSource as additional fature and bingo!

Thanks everyone here!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the logic that you want:

```
WHERE ([rentnr] = @rentnr OR @rentnr IS NULL OR @rentnr = '') AND
      ([apartman] = @apartman OR @apartman IS NULL OR @partman = '')
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Just tried your code but same again. No records in GV on page load, DDLs are empty as result of asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" in asp code. I select number on first DDL  and gridview DataBind but no records in gridview. Then I selected number in second DDL and finaly GV show filtered records. But no my goal, want all records on page load and cascade filtering...any suggestion - tnx

Comment: Instead of `IS NULL` use `= ''`

Comment: Hi Craig, same again, after used ""  In Query Builder VS2012  when tried with ""  system display error Invalid error for cell because value is not recognized as valid. As I said, must be decimal... but if i use NULL, again nothing...